# Why Thread.Sleep(0) time-slice handled over threads with lower priorities?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-priority

As far as i know Thread.Sleep(0) gives time-slice only to another thread with the same or higher priority.
I did some test app:

```
class Program
{
    public static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ThreadProc: {1}, prio {2} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                i, Thread.CurrentThread.Priority);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t2.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;

        Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)1;

        t.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t2.Join();
        t.Join();
    }
}
```

This is simulation single core CPU, as I understand here should be executed only mainly thread with Highest priority, but what I see:
Low prio thread keep changing high prio every operation [image: interchanging threads]

Threads are changing one another.
(Of course in beginning and at the end there is different situation, but Highest thread should always get more time-slice)

Why this is not like this all the time?
Low prio thread MUST be executed less amount of time
[image: high priority thread first]

Comment: If the value of the millisecondsTimeout argument is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run... Your main thread is not ready to run it is waiting for t and t2 to finish (Join method)

Comment: This test is getting screwed up because of a lock you cannot see.  It is buried inside the Console class, it ensures that only one thread at a time can execute Console.Write().  It ensures that output doesn't get intermingled.  These threads don't execute any real code, they are only fighting over that lock.  The OS thread scheduler bumps up the priority of a thread that is waiting for a lock and can acquire it.  Insert `for (long j = 0; j < 1000L * 1000 * 50; j++) ;`after the Sleep(0), thus having these threads do real work, and you now see the result you hoped for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 threads: `t` (high priority) and `t2` (low priority), and also main thread. When high priority thread executes `Thread.Sleep(0)` - the only other thread it can give its time slice is `t2`, because even though it has lower priority - there are just no other options. Main thread is blocked by `Join()` and has no code to run, it doesn't need time slice.

To see behavior your are expecting - add one more thread with high priority:

```
public static void Main() {
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    t2.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;

    Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    t3.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

    Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr) 1;

    t.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();
    t3.Join();
    t2.Join();
    t.Join();
}
```

Then you will see that high priority threads give their time slices to each other, so they both will almost exclusively execute their loops, and only after they are done - low priority thread will execute its loop.

Comment: Looks like you are absolutely right, just confused with description on MSDN and other discussions regarding Thread.Sleep(0)

MSDN: "If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread is not suspended."